# How to wait for all Disruptor messages to be consumed in a test case

Tags: java, event-sourcing, circular-buffer, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I'm trying to unit test an application which publishes/consumes messages using the [Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) ring buffer. In the test I would like to

1. Configure the [Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/javadoc/com.lmax.disruptor/com/lmax/disruptor/dsl/Disruptor.html) and it's [EventHandler](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/javadoc/com.lmax.disruptor/com/lmax/disruptor/EventHandler.html)s
2. Publish messages onto the ring buffer
3. Wait for all messages to be consumed by all [EventHandler](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/javadoc/com.lmax.disruptor/com/lmax/disruptor/EventHandler.html)s
4. Perform some assertions

Is there a simple way that I can wait for the messages to be consumed (step 3 above)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with a loop which completes when `RingBuffer.remainingCapacity()` is equal to `Disruptor.getBufferSize()`

```java
public class MyTest {
    private Disruptor<MyEvent> disruptor;
  
    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        disruptor = new Disruptor<>(...);
        disruptor.handleEventsWith(...);
        disruptor.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        disruptor.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        disruptor.publishEvent(...);
        disruptor.publishEvent(...);

        awaitRingBuffer();
        
        assertThat(...);
    }
 
    private void awaitRingBuffer() throws InterruptedException {
        RingBuffer<MyEvent> ringBuffer = disruptor.getRingBuffer();
        while (ringBuffer.remainingCapacity() != disruptor.getBufferSize()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```